# Media queries which work for both width and height

Tags: html, css, media

I have a media query to check screen height like below but irrespective of screen height (1200 or 1050) only the first query applies and sets height=94%.
can anyone please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1920px) and (max-device-height: 1200px) {
     .tab-content-parent-ht {
        height:94%;            
      }
 }

@media screen and (min-device-width:1920px) and (max-device-height: 1050px) {
    .tab-content-parent-ht {
         height:91.5%;            
     }
 }
```

Comment: Suggest using viewport units

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your code like below:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1920px) and (min-device-height: 1051px) {
     .tab-content-parent-ht {
        height:94%;            
      }
 }

@media screen and (min-device-width:1920px) and (max-device-height: 1050px) {
    .tab-content-parent-ht {
         height:91.5%;            
     }
 }
```